# Преобразовать и сохранить полученные данные в виде списка или кортежа

Tags: python, list

Всем доброго времени суток!
Есть данные, полученные от событий, в виде вложенного списка ... [[1343  291]]  [[1343  284]] и т.д. Можно перевести их в булево значение в виде True  это "1", а False это "0", и сохранить их в .txt или другом файле?

Comment: а какой алгоритм? где у вас в полученном списке True или 1? перечитайте свой вопрос.

Comment: Можно, если вы явно опишете алгоритм такого перевода. Подозреваю, что речь идет о попадании объекта в некоторую зону (судя по другим вашим вопросам)?

Comment: Абсолютно верно, пишу программу для видеонаблюдения, система основана, пока как черновик на изменение кадров frame_1 и frame_2, детектор движения. Есть область roi, в которой происходит это движение. В этой области появляется человек, и при его появлении должен создаваться отчет в виде графика или txt файла, т.е. какое время он находится в зоне детектора движения. Но не могу создать отчет для босса(назову его так), так как опыта пока мало. Прошу простить за некачественный язык, сленгом пока тоже не владею как вы.

Comment: Разобрался с True и False. Понял, что лучше сохранить данные сначала в .txt, а потом их использовать и для графика и для отчета.